# Is there a way to create endless stream with custom character?

Tags: files, scripting, binary

I need to create an endless stream of characters like /dev/zero but I need it to spam custom character (like 'a') instead of 0x00. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: yes a​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @mikeserv "yes a" inserts a new line after each character. and i need this stream to be a file like /dev/zero because i want to use it with dd

Comment: `yes a|dd cbs=1 conv=block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Apply the Unix philosophy: combine tools together.

```
</dev/zero tr '\0' 'a'
```